# Can I mount data to host filesystem from docker's VOLUME CREATE?

Tags: docker

It's great that I can make a volume to share between applications.

`docker volume create --name hello`

However, if I wanted to use my host's IDE to edit this data how could I?

Comment: As of a commit 3 days ago, it looks like mount propagation is the way to go. https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/volume I don't have a clue about that yet.

Comment: @michaelbahr Holy crap, thanks for the great tip! More detailed info on https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/man/docker-create.1.md I'm going to read up and probably answer my question... unless you want to give it a shot for pointing it out

Comment: I also saw that document, however it does not provide a simple solution vor `docker create volume` :/ Should go with the answer of @VonC for now.

Answer (score 1):

For now, you would need to [mount a host directory (as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)) in order to be able to edit a file from the host directly in a container.

```
-v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

> This command mounts the host directory, `/src/webapp`, into the container at `/opt/webapp`. If the path `/opt/webapp` already exists inside the container’s image, the `/src/webapp` mount overlays but does not remove the pre-existing content.